# Why php can't print data from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP failed to print data of two columns of a mysql table，the result only shows the first row of data which proved to be right,with the rest rows show 
" Undefined offset".

```php
                    $query1='select MNO from mima01 order by MNO;';
                    $query2='select MTYPE from mima01 order by MNO;';
                    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$query1);
                    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
                    $username=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
                    $usertype=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

                    $count='select count(*) from mima01;';
                    $usercount=mysqli_query($conn,$count);
                    $usernum=mysqli_fetch_array($usercount);

                    for($i=0;$i<$usernum[0];$i++) {
                        echo '<tr><td style="text-align:center">' ;
                        echo $username[$i];
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '<td style="text-align:center">' ;
                        echo $usertype[$i];
                        echo '</td></tr>';
                    }
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` retrieves a single row, not all rows. You need to loop through the results to get all of them. PHP docs do a very bad job at showing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten your code to the normal way you would walk through a query result:

```
$query  = 'select MNO, MTYPE from mima01 order by MNO;';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td style="text-align:center">' . 
         $data['MNO'] . 
         '</td>' .
         '<td style="text-align:center">' . 
         $data['MTYPE'] . 
         '</td></tr>';
}
```

Please note that I have no way to run this code so I can't be a 100% sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand I think your solution is:

```php
 $query='SELECT MNO,MTYPE FROM mima01 ORDER BY MNO DECS;'; //use DECS|ASC
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 $username=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// to count the rows
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);;
echo $count;

// to display data
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) {
    echo '<tr><td style="text-align:center">';
    echo $row['MNO'];
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td style="text-align:center">';
    echo $row['MTYPE'];
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Hope it was helpful